# Operator overloading question

Tags: c#, operators

Suppose I have a class:

```
 public class Vector
 {
   public float X { get; set; }

   public Vector(float xvalue)
   {
       X = xvalue;
   }

   public static Vector operator +(Vector v1, Vector v2) 
   {
       return new Vector(v1.X + v2.X);
   }
 }
```

Have a derived class:

```
 public class MyVector : Vector
 {
     public static MyVector operator +(MyVector v1, MyVector v2)
     {
         return new MyVector(v1.X + v2.X);
     }

    public MyVector(float xvalue):base(xvalue)
    {

    }
 }
```

No if I execute folowing code:

```
 Vector v1 = new MyVector(10);    //type MyVector

 Vector v2 = new MyVector(20);    //type MyVector

 Vector v3 = v1 + v2;             //executed operator is of Vector class
```

Here is executed Vector's + operator, but the type of v1 and v2 is `MyVector`, so v3 is Vector type at this point.

Why this happens?

Comment: What you are expecting is that operator overload resolution uses *double virtual dispatch* but in reality it uses *non virtual dispatch*. It would be awesome if operators were resolved via double virtual dispatch, but the language does not support that feature. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/09/double-your-dispatch-double-your-fun.aspx for more thoughts on this.

Comment: Got it, the problem that by just looking on code executed I would say, v3 is MyVector or may be other derived type, but not based one. awesome... Instead here dominates rule of just "simple" static function rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the type of the variables `v1` and `v2` are `Vector`, not `MyVector`.  Operator overloads are static methods that are resolved by the compiler at *compile-time*, not at runtime; they cannot be overridden.

`v1` and `v2` will have to be typed `MyVector` for the compiler to select the overload defined in the `MyVector` class.

Optionally, define a method `public virtual Vector Add(Vector other)` on the `Vector` class and have `MyVector` override it.  Then call this method from the `operator+` method of `Vector` and this will work as you expected.  (`MyVector` would then not need to define `operator+` itself.)

Comment: @Tigran: Not quite, but close. The compiler looks at the compile-time type of both sides and makes a list of all the "+" operators available on both types. It then does overload resolution on that list as though the operation was a call to a two-argument method "operator+(a, b)".

Answer (score 1):

Like [cdhowie answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768015/operator-overloading-question/6768052#6768052), the method resolution is done at compile type.

But if you're working with C# 4.0, you can try the following.

```
void foo()
{
   Vector v1 = new MyVector(10);    // type MyVector
   Vector v2 = new MyVector(20);    // type MyVector
   Vector v3 = v1 + v2;             // Vector.operator + called
   bar(v1, v2);
}

void bar(Vector p_v1, Vector p_v2)
{
   dynamic v1 = p_v1;               // dynamic type
   dynamic v2 = p_v2;               // dynamic type
   Vector v3 = v1 + v2;             // MyVector.operator + called
}
```

To see that in the `bar()` method, the method call resolution will be done at runtime, using the true type of `v1` and `v2`, instead of the perceived type at compile time (as in `foo()`).

:-)

P.S.: Delaying type resolution at runtime can be slower, and less safe (as errors that should have been caught at compile time will be discovered during execution).